# Multiple copy of IIS Site, Databases and Windows services

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, windows-services, iis-7.5

I have a Big Application build in asp.net 4.5.1 Web form. The Application has two Windows Services. This is a product that we host for different vendors. The client Requirement is to have Separate URL, Database and separate Services. we are getting vendors rapidly, now this became a big problem for me, to update, each url separately, to trace any db changes across the database and implement that separately, and to create separate windows service applications for each vendor and to install that separately on the server. Although I have put code in class libraries so that is shared among all the web and the Windows Service application. but there are other settings, like encryption key, the connection strings to each database, the email settings etc.

can someone please guide me how can I manage multiple copy of same application when there are Windows Service applications too.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is the application code the same or are there individual modifications per customer? Sounds like the differences you mention could be specified in different config files.

Comment: yes you are right, there are differences only in some settings, like emails, connectionstring, email subjects, encryption keys, domain name and the users uploaded files, excel csv etc. the functional code is all same for all the vendors who will have separate urls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am doing similar things by using different build configurations for that.

1. Create a new build (solution) configuration for each customer. Right click solution and select 'Configuration Manager'.
2. Add new configuration with customer name and select to copy settings preferably from Release config.
3. Once you've done that you are able to switch between those configs next to the debug button in VS.
4. Go to your web project, right click your Web.config file and select 'Add config Transform'
5. New config files are created (Web.[ConfigName].config) and placed as sub node under the Web.config file.

These new files are used to transform the original Web.config depending on the selected solution configuration. There's some information in the transform file on how to use it, it is not difficult.
If you would go for automated build process later on, the solution config is the key for that as well. Also if you define publish templates (e.g. to create web deploy packages), you are able to select the config. The transformed web.config is then automatically put into the package.